# Call a method in validate_uniqueness in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can we call a method in 'validate_uniqueness'

I have a column named "profile_url" which should be unique for all users. I'm checking its uniqueness using

```
validates_uniqueness_of :profile_url, message: "has already been taken"
```

I want this to redirect to a method if this validation hit occurs.  Is it possible in ruby on rails to assign a method along with this validate uniqueness line.

Comment: redirect to a method? where? in controller? in model?

Comment: in model..............

Comment: No. There's no way to redirect to a method if validation fails. However, you can use `after_validation` callback and check if there are any errors on object.

Comment: You can try a `after_validation` callback.

Comment: Good. But how would the hook you guys mentioned will understand from which validation this event came? Any way to track..?

Comment: Yeah, how should i know which validation triggered this after_validation

Comment: This call back will be triggered after all the validations are run. Now you can inspect the errors to see if the uniqueness validation failed.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use a custom validation like this:

```
class User
  validate :verify_unique_profile_url

  def verify_unique_profile_url
    if User.exists? profile_url: profile_url
      errors.add :profile_url, 'has already been taken'
    end
  end
end
```

More information can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations).

Comment: Your condition won't work if the existing user try to edit their settings/proile. It should be `User.exists?(profile_url: profile_url) && self.new_record?`

Comment: @Surya This validation should probably also be run when the user updates the `profile_url`. In that case your suggestion will 'skip' the validation. What you probably mean is that a check should be added to see whether or not the profile_url exists on your own `User` record.

Comment: I see, you're right. Then probably one more check to see if user's profile is been changed. Something like: `User.exists?(profile_url: profile_url) && (self.new_record? || self.profile_url_changed? )`

Answer (score 0):

```
validates_uniqueness_of :profile_url, message: "has already been taken", if: :method_name?
```

This validation will fire only if the method returns true.

Comment: You can either check inside the controller if the error hash includes the key "profile_url" then redirect to your desired method.